# how to remove a conflicting package

Tags: fedora, yum

I am attempting to do a yum update and I get this

```
admin@localhost ~$ sudo yum update
Loaded plugins: langpacks, priorities, refresh-packagekit
adobe-linux-x86_64                                                                                    |  951 B  00:00:00     
infinality                                                                                            | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
infinality-noarch                                                                                     | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
intellinuxgraphics                                                                                    |  951 B  00:00:00     
rpmfusion-free-updates                                                                                | 3.3 kB  00:00:00     
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates                                                                             | 3.3 kB  00:00:00     
updates/20/x86_64/metalink                                                                            |  17 kB  00:00:00     
105 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package NetworkManager.x86_64 1:0.9.9.0-20.git20131003.fc20 will be updated
---> Package NetworkManager.x86_64 1:0.9.9.0-45.git20131003.fc20 will be updated
---> Package NetworkManager.x86_64 1:0.9.9.0-46.git20131003.fc20 will be an update
---> Package NetworkManager-glib.x86_64 1:0.9.9.0-20.git20131003.fc20 will be updated
---> Package NetworkManager-glib.x86_64 1:0.9.9.0-45.git20131003.fc20 will be updated
---> Package NetworkManager-glib.x86_64 1:0.9.9.0-46.git20131003.fc20 will be an update
---> Package ctags.i386 0:5.8-1 will be updated
---> Package ctags.x86_64 0:5.8-16.fc20 will be an update
---> Package libdrm.i686 0:2.4.54-1.fc20 will be updated
---> Package libdrm.x86_64 0:2.4.54-1.fc20 will be updated
---> Package libdrm.i686 0:2.4.54-20.intel20142 will be an update
---> Package libdrm.x86_64 0:2.4.54-20.intel20142 will be an update
---> Package mesa-dri-drivers.x86_64 0:10.1.5-1.20140607.fc20 will be updated
---> Package mesa-dri-drivers.x86_64 0:10.2.2-20.intel20142 will be an update
---> Package mesa-filesystem.x86_64 0:10.1.5-1.20140607.fc20 will be updated
---> Package mesa-filesystem.x86_64 0:10.2.2-20.intel20142 will be an update
---> Package mesa-libEGL.i686 0:10.1.5-1.20140607.fc20 will be updated
---> Package mesa-libEGL.x86_64 0:10.1.5-1.20140607.fc20 will be updated
---> Package mesa-libEGL.i686 0:10.2.2-20.intel20142 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libtinfo.so.5 for package: mesa-libEGL-10.2.2-20.intel20142.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libelf.so.1(ELFUTILS_1.5) for package: mesa-libEGL-10.2.2-20.intel20142.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libelf.so.1 for package: mesa-libEGL-10.2.2-20.intel20142.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libLLVM-3.4.so for package: mesa-libEGL-10.2.2-20.intel20142.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libelf.so.1(ELFUTILS_1.0) for package: mesa-libEGL-10.2.2-20.intel20142.i686
---> Package mesa-libEGL.x86_64 0:10.2.2-20.intel20142 will be an update
---> Package mesa-libGL.i686 0:10.1.5-1.20140607.fc20 will be updated
---> Package mesa-libGL.x86_64 0:10.1.5-1.20140607.fc20 will be updated
---> Package mesa-libGL.i686 0:10.2.2-20.intel20142 will be an update
---> Package mesa-libGL.x86_64 0:10.2.2-20.intel20142 will be an update
---> Package mesa-libgbm.i686 0:10.1.5-1.20140607.fc20 will be updated
---> Package mesa-libgbm.x86_64 0:10.1.5-1.20140607.fc20 will be updated
---> Package mesa-libgbm.i686 0:10.2.2-20.intel20142 will be an update
---> Package mesa-libgbm.x86_64 0:10.2.2-20.intel20142 will be an update
---> Package mesa-libglapi.i686 0:10.1.5-1.20140607.fc20 will be updated
---> Package mesa-libglapi.x86_64 0:10.1.5-1.20140607.fc20 will be updated
---> Package mesa-libglapi.i686 0:10.2.2-20.intel20142 will be an update
---> Package mesa-libglapi.x86_64 0:10.2.2-20.intel20142 will be an update
---> Package mesa-libwayland-egl.x86_64 0:9.2.3-1.20131114.fc20 will be updated
---> Package mesa-libwayland-egl.x86_64 0:10.1.5-1.20140607.fc20 will be updated
---> Package mesa-libwayland-egl.x86_64 0:10.2.2-20.intel20142 will be an update
---> Package mesa-libxatracker.x86_64 0:9.2.3-1.20131114.fc20 will be updated
---> Package mesa-libxatracker.x86_64 0:10.1.5-1.20140607.fc20 will be updated
---> Package mesa-libxatracker.x86_64 0:10.2.2-20.intel20142 will be an update
---> Package protobuf.x86_64 0:2.5.0-5.fc20 will be updated
---> Package protobuf.x86_64 0:2.5.0-11.fc20 will be an update
---> Package protobuf-compiler.x86_64 0:2.5.0-5.fc20 will be updated
---> Package protobuf-compiler.x86_64 0:2.5.0-11.fc20 will be an update
---> Package xorg-x11-drv-intel.x86_64 0:2.21.15-7.fc20 will be updated
---> Package xorg-x11-drv-intel.x86_64 0:2.99.911-20.intel20142 will be an update
---> Package xorg-x11-drv-vmware.x86_64 0:13.0.2-4.20140613git82c9b0c.fc20 will be updated
---> Package xorg-x11-drv-vmware.x86_64 0:13.0.2-20.intel20142 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package elfutils-libelf.i686 0:0.160-1.fc20 will be installed
---> Package llvm-libs.i686 0:3.4-6.fc20 will be installed
---> Package ncurses-libs.i686 0:5.9-12.20130511.fc20 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
       cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
       pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:

         1. You have an upgrade for elfutils-libelf which is missing some
            dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
            solve this by installing an older version of elfutils-libelf of the
            different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
            yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
            requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
            --exclude elfutils-libelf.otherarch ... this should give you an error
            message showing the root cause of the problem.

         2. You have multiple architectures of elfutils-libelf installed, but
            yum can only see an upgrade for one of those architectures.
            If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
            can remove the one with the missing update and everything
            will work.

         3. You have duplicate versions of elfutils-libelf installed already.
            You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.

       ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
       this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
       do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
       much more problems).

       Protected multilib versions: elfutils-libelf-0.160-1.fc20.i686 != elfutils-libelf-0.157-1.fc20.x86_64
Error: Protected multilib versions: llvm-libs-3.4-6.fc20.i686 != llvm-libs-3.3-0.10.rc3.fc20.x86_64
```

I would like to know what other packages use  elfutils-libelf-0.160-1.fc20.i686 
If they are not important I will remove them and hopefully that might solve this problem. If there is another way for me to resolve this issue please let me know I am open to suggestions.

I tried this

```
> sudo yum erase  elfutils-libelf-0.160-1.fc20.i686 
Loaded plugins: langpacks, priorities, refresh-packagekit
No Match for argument: elfutils-libelf-0.160-1.fc20.i686
No Packages marked for removal
```

Comment: You can run yum erase elfutils-libelf and before anything will be removed you will be prompted to confirm the removal of dependent packages.

Comment: it marked the packages with "will be erased" but it did not ask me to confirm. What does that mean ?

Comment: I meant you can do it without actually removing them since you need to confirm the removal. Now you know what are the dependent packages. Did that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You have x86_64 and x86 (64 and 32 bit) versions installed, and for some reason the available versions don't match (require different versions of something).

You could try to remove the i686 versions with:

```
yum erase elfutils-libelf.i686 llvm-libs.i686
```

This will ask you if you want to delete those (and the packages that depend on them).

In any case, Fedora 20 is past end-of-life, please do upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `yum erase elfutils-libelf` to the dependent packages that will need to be removed in order to remove elfutils-libelf.

Comment: Oh okay those are a lot. Is there a way  to remove only the x86 version ? I get this     `Protected multilib versions: elfutils-libelf-0.160-1.fc20.i686 != elfutils-libelf-0.157-1.fc20.x86_64
Error: Protected multilib versions: llvm-libs-3.4-6.fc20.i686 != llvm-libs-3.3-0.10.rc3.fc20.x86_64`

Comment: You should first clean yum's cache and if the prblem persist, you will need to manually remove the protection, look [here for instructions](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/57783). You can also run the update without elfutils-libelf, look [here for someone with the same problem](http://www.forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?p=1713166)